# Python 3 can't import PyGObject

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, pygobject

I'm trying to use PyGObject with Python 3, (either on Debian or Linux Mint) so I can use Gtk3+ and Glade for creating GUIs.

The problem is this:

In Python 3:

```
import gi
```

says module 'gi' not found.

I installed python3-gi from the repository, and Python 3 still says module not found when I try to import it.

However, Python 2 detects the module.
In Python 2, if I do

```
import gi
```

It works, but not with Python 3. I'm only interested in Python 3.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you have `python3-gi` not `python-gi`?

Comment: What is your Python version?

Comment: I have the same problem with pynput, I did `>pip3 install pynput` and `>pip install pynput`, both tell me it already exisis. But while python 2 detects it python3 does not and gives me a `ModuleNotFoundError`

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with a different Linux distro which had PyGObject already installed for Python 3 - [Ubuntu-MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/). Before, I was using Linux Mint.

Answer (score 0):

the solution which worked out for me

```
pip install pycairo
pip install pyGObject
```